# Failed to start RabbitMQ broker

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to install rabbitmq from last 16 hours and tried on ubunutu 18 and 16.04 by following commands:

https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/72f0ad39e11915c0077d544b50096b50

I don't know why it is not starting:

```
    rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-10-31 05:19:15 EDT; 11ms ago
      Process: 723 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c while ps -p $MAINPID >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 340 ExecStop=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 32210 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 32210 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Oct 31 05:19:15 vps47024 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
    Oct 31 05:19:15 vps47024 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Unit entered ...e.
    Oct 31 05:19:15 vps47024 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with r...'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     rabbitmq-server
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried with this

```
    https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/rabbitmq-server?action=remove
```

But same issue again..

Kindly help me out on this!

Comment: Please carefully read the output! It states this: `Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.` Without seeing the full output there's no way to know why RabbitMQ didn't start. Also, look for log files in `/var/log/rabbitmq` and for an `erl_crash.dump` file in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia`. Both can contain clues. Finally, you can use my Ubuntu 16 `Vagrantfile` for ideas: [link](https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/6ab2971999304f3e44893fa64944e810)